# Search component with a dropdown using svelte and shadcn-svelte

Tags: search, components, dropdown, svelte, shadcnui

I'm trying to create a search component using `Svelte` and `shadcn-svelte` UI component library,

Where I'll have a dropdown visible below the search input, when the user type a text that does exist in the `data` array, otherwise the dropdown should be hidden.

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { Input } from '$lib/components/ui/input';
    import * as DropdownMenu from '$lib/components/ui/dropdown-menu';

    let searchValue = '';
    
    let filteredResults: string[] = [];
    let isDropdownOpen = false;

    const data = [
        'California',
        'North Carolina',
        'North Dakota',
        'South Carolina',
        'South Dakota',
        'Michigan',
        'Tennessee',
        'Nevada',
        'New Hampshire',
        'New Jersey'
    ];

    function handleInput() {
        filteredResults = data.filter((item) =>
            item.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())
        );

        isDropdownOpen = (filteredResults.length > 0 && searchValue !== '');
    }
    function handleItemSelection(item: string) {
        console.log(`${item} selected`);
    }
</script>

<Input bind:value={searchValue} on:input={handleInput} placeholder="Search..." />
<DropdownMenu.Root open={isDropdownOpen} disableFocusFirstItem={true}>
    <DropdownMenu.Trigger asChild let:builder>
        <Button builders={[builder]} class="h-0 m-0 p-0" variant="outline"></Button>
    </DropdownMenu.Trigger>
    <DropdownMenu.Content>
        <DropdownMenu.Group>
            {#each filteredResults as item}
                <DropdownMenu.Item on:click={() => handleItemSelection(item)}>{item}</DropdownMenu.Item>
            {/each}
        </DropdownMenu.Group>
    </DropdownMenu.Content>
</DropdownMenu.Root>
```

My issue is once I start typing, the drop-down menu will show up but, the focus will transfer to the drop-down menu and that will prevent me from typing.

Comment: Never used ShadCDN but have you tried binding the value of open to your `isDropdownOpen` variable? `bind:open={isDropdownOpen}`

Comment: @JHeth, Well, actually I managed to resolve that issue by adding a "trigger" ""
```<DropdownMenu.Trigger asChild let:builder>
  <Button builders={[builder]} class="h-0 m-0 p-0" variant="outline"></Button>
 </DropdownMenu.Trigger>```
But now I have a new issue, I've updated the question.

Comment: that's probably related to the `disableFocusFirstItem` in the Bits underlying API for ShadCDN [API Reference](https://www.bits-ui.com/docs/components/dropdown-menu#dropdownmenuroot:~:text=disableFocusFirstItem)

Comment: @JHeth I've already set that to `true`, and indeed, it did dis-activate the focus on the first item, but still the focus will be on the drop-down menu itself.

Comment: @ZSmain Did u find a solution for that problem? got exactly the same problem..

Comment: @meinharttom, not yet, In the meanwhile I'm using a third party library called "svelte-typeahead", but I still want to implement mine, because I want to have custom search that will change behavior based on selected options